# Is 'going blind' simple future verb?

Tags: verbs

Is 'going blind' simple future verb?

And you're gonna spend the next three
months **going blind** on paperwork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither simple nor future.

"Going" is the so-called present participle form.   It should be called the continuous participle.   This form does not have any tense, but it does have the continuous aspect.   We can use this aspect in all three tenses:

- I was going blind. -- past continuous
- I am going blind.  -- present continuous
- I will be going blind.  -- future continuous

The aspect that we call "simple" does not use auxiliary verbs the way that the continuous and perfect aspects do:

- I went blind.  -- simple past
- I go blind.  -- simple present
- I will go blind.  -- simple future

The simple future is a finite form.   It has a definite tense.   In English, finite verbs require a subject.   In the example above, the subject of "will go" is "I".

The participle is a non-finite form.   It does not have a definite tense.   In English, non-finite verbs do not require a subject.   Consider your example sentence:

- You are going to spend the next three months going blind from paperwork.

The verb "are going" is a present continuous verb with the subject "you", but "going blind from paperwork" is a participial phrase that has no subject.   Rather than acting as a predicate, it acts as an object complement to the infinitive "to spend", modifying "the next three months".

Comment: Complete answer.Thanks. Can I use participial phrases in formal writing?

Comment: Absolutely.  The sentence "You are going to spend the next three months going blind from paperwork." is acceptable in a formal register.  The sentence "And you're gonna spend the next three months going blind on paperwork." isn't.  The differences are: 1) starting a sentence with a coordinating conjunction, 2) using contractions, especially the informal contraction "gonna", and 3) choosing a non-idiomatic preposition in the participial phrase.  Participles and their phrases are common features of the language, regardless of register.

Answer (score 0):

"going blind" is not simple future, because there is not the word "will".This verb is present continuous tense, but it can describe your intend in future.For example,"I am going to play tennis".